# recyclerView reference from a child layout, included <include/> in a parent layout

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have a fragment which includes another layout. I have no problem accessing any of the other views in this layout (TextViews, ImageViews, CardViews), except for the RecyclervView in specific.

This post -> [How to use recyclerview with include layout properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45221818/how-to-use-recyclerview-with-include-layout-properly) <- addresses a similar situation where the user was getting a run time error. I am able to compile and run the app without any runtime errors. The problem that I am getting, is that the RecyclerView does not display any of the information from the adapter that I have made. I tested the adapter separately to see if that was the issue and it was not, as it worked perfectly fine when implemented separately in the parent layout without an  tag. I could easily just code the actual layout into the main fragment, but i need to reuse that specific layout various times through out the application so its necessary to include it using the  tag.

I have provided the xml layout, fragment class, SetViewHolder class as well as the adapter view below.

**note:** my adapterView uses a SetViewHolder class from recyclerView.

**XML Layout**

```
<VideoView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|center"
    android:id="@+id/vvLive"/>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
    android:background="@color/lightGray"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="375dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <include
            layout="@layout/home_intro_category"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/slide_show1"
            layout="@layout/image_slide_show_card_holder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />


    </LinearLayout>



</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**Fragment Class**

```
public class HomeFrag extends Fragment {

private BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior;
private HomeViewModel viewModel;
private TextView tvHeaderCS1, tvSubCS1;
private SlideAdapter adapter;
RecyclerView rvSlide1;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_frag, container, false);
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);

    return viewGroup;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //initialize views
    View bottomSheet = view.findViewById(R.id.bottomSheet);
    bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HALF_EXPANDED);
    CardView cvSlide1 = view.findViewById(R.id.slide_show1);
    rvSlide1 = cvSlide1.findViewById(R.id.rvItems);
    tvHeaderCS1 = cvSlide1.findViewById(R.id.hdMain);
    tvSubCS1 = cvSlide1.findViewById(R.id.hdSub);

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    viewModel.populateList().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(String s) {
            try {
                GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
                Gson gson = builder.create();
                List<Item> itemsList = new ArrayList<>();
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(s);

                for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                    Item item = gson.fromJson(array.getString(i), Item.class);
                    itemsList.add(item);
                }

                LinearLayoutManager linearLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
                adapter = new SlideAdapter(getActivity(), itemsList);
                rvSlide1.setLayoutManager(linearLayout);
                rvSlide1.setAdapter(adapter); //no problem with adapter, but not showing anything****


                //slide shows headers and subs
                tvHeaderCS1.setText("Items Recently On Air");
                tvSubCS1.setText("");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

}
```

**Adapter Class**

```
public class SlideAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SetViewHolder> {

private Activity activity;
List<Item> items;

public SlideAdapter(Activity activity, List<Item> items) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.items = items;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public SetViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.slideshow_card_item, parent, false);
    return new SetViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SetViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.tvProductNameSlide.setText(items.get(position).getItemName());
    holder.tvPreviousPriceSlide.setText(String.valueOf(items.get(position).getItemPreviousPrice()));
    holder.tvSalePriceSlide.setText(String.valueOf(items.get(position).getItemSalePrice()));
    Glide.with(activity).load(items.get(position).getItemURL())
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.ivProductSlideShow);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}
}
```

**SetViewHolder Class**
    public class SetViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

```
public TextView tvProductNameSlide, tvPreviousPriceSlide, tvSalePriceSlide;
public ImageView ivProductSlideShow;

public SetViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);


    tvProductNameSlide = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductName);
    tvPreviousPriceSlide = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPreviousPrice);
    tvSalePriceSlide = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSalePrice);
    ivProductSlideShow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivProduct);

}
```

}

My goal is to populate the recyclerView with objects (name, item, image) with another layout (cardView). I have tested the adapter on its own by implementing a RecyclerView directly in the HomeFrag.class (Main Fragment where i use the  tag) and the adapter works perfectly fine.

When I try to populate it by accessing the RecyclerView from inside the  layout, I am getting an empty recyclerview and no runtime crashes. While doing this, as a user has suggested, i also logged the getItemCount method from inside the adapter to see whether i was actually receiving data, and the result returned item size of 19.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** updated results from a debugging method suggested by user. provided updated details regarding fragment, and child fragment properties.

Comment: May be your String s is null?? have you checked the value of s from the observer?

Comment: @NishanKhadka yes i have checked the value from the observer. the string is not null. i have implemented the RecyclerView directly into the fragment (without using the include tag) and it works perfectly. but when i try to reference a recyclerview in an included layout, it does not show anything

Comment: let's put a log on the method getItemCount() of the recyclerview adapter and see the size of the list that's populated, if it does't return 0 then, probably it's a layout issue .. where one layout is overlapped by another

Comment: @NishanKhadka the size returns 19 (my sample data). as i have mentioned, i tested out the adapter by implementing a RecyclerView into the main fragment, and it works fine.

Comment: then your RecyclerView is populated, it's most probably the issue with your layout, why not try giving fixed height on the included layouts and see if the RecyclerView will be displayed :)

Comment: @NishanKhadka nope still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

On the (include) layout where You use `RecyclerView`, add `app:layout_behavior`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/conversation"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Also, try to do one more thing: call `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` before 
calling `setAdapter()`:

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: the scrolling isn't the issue. none of the views in the RecyclerView are being displayed. i have tried implementing the RecyclerView in the actual homeFrag and it works fine. Either way, i tried your recommendation and still no fix. thank you for the effort.